# IEumerable list in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am new to C# but not new to OOP, I know Java very well. I have been thrown into a project which the guys which were coding it us this alot:

```
public List<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> generateCriteriaOptions()
```

I understand generics in Java but cannot under this statement. From what I understand a generic List would be List, so its makes no since to me that you have a generic type within a generic type. Can  someone please explain this code for me.

Here is the full method:

```
 public List<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> generateCriteriaOptions()
    {
        List<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> criteriaLists = new List<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>();
        List<Object> list = new List<Object>();
        Patient p = new Patient();
        list.Add(new {key="",val="All"});
        list.Add(new { key = KEY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, val = "Account #" });
        list.Add(new { key = KEY_PATIENT_TYPE, val = "Patient Type" });
        list.Add(new { key = KEY_SUBBED_TO, val = "Outsource Company" });
        criteriaLists.Add(new SelectList(list,"key","val"));

        return criteriaLists;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Generics in Java are very different from generics in .NET, because there is no *type erasure* in .NET. You can specify that you are returning a list of IEmumerable, and then add List objects to your list. Because List implements IEmumerable, this is not an error.

In your case, however, an object of type SelectList is added. I would make a guess and say that SelectList implements an IEnumerable of SelectListItem, or inherits a class that does it. I would also guess that there are other classes that work as a supply of SelectListItems in addition to the SelectList. Since the List returned from your method specifies an instance of a generic interface rather than a class as the list element type, you can mix and match different implementations of IEnumerable in the same list.

Comment: Great answers all, so from my understanding this is nothing more then a list which contains elements that are of IEnumerable<SelectListItem> thank you for the better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the return object is simply a list of some sort of collection of `SelectListItems` (i.e. a collection of collections).  Not much different from `SelectListItem[][]`.

Answer (score 0):

`List<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>` means list of `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. In other words each element of the list implements `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. So it's a list of `SelectListItem` sequences.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, the program I am working with generates a drop down list which selections another drop down list, so returning a another IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list makes sense.